# How to work with promises (axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const tweetCall = (state, action) => {
  let results = axios.get('/tweet').then(res => {
    return res.data
  });

  console.log(results)

};

const tweetCallReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TWEET":
      tweetCall(state, action)
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  } //end of switch

};

export default tweetCallReducer;
```

In the TweetCall() function i want to set results equal to the response(res) of the data sent back from the server, but it just gets set to : Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}**proto**: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]:

How can i traverse a promise object or how can i set results equal to the data from the server.

Comment: This won't work because you are treating the promise like it returns a value immediately rather than asynchronously. But it's hard to tell what you want as a final result because you return the same thing from `tweetCallReducer()` regardless of what happens. What should happen after `tweetCallReducer`?

Comment: in your case `results` will always be undefined because the promise is a async code which means you have to wait until it's resolved so the right place to console your data is inside the `.then` block

Comment: it shoud give me an arrray of tweets that i have set up in the server

Comment: how Can i make it wait until it gets the result? or how can i traverse the Promise Tree?

Comment: Looks you are using Redux, right? Better to think about using `Redux-thunk`

Comment: Ok I will try it out! Does it help wait for promises?